# Absolute URL's with link_to...Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to generate absolute URL's in rails using link to? [NOTE: THIS IS IN A MAILER]

I tried to do:

```
<%= link_to root_url, root_url%>
```

But I get a runtime error:

*Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set default_url_options[:host]*

I need this to be dynamic because the application will run on a wildcard domain (*.domain.com)

Comment: Why do you need the URL to be absolute in this case? A relative URL will be relative to the current host, which sounds like what you want

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that it's because this link is going to be embedded in an e-mail. Is that what's happening here Chris?

Comment: appears possible using :only_path => false see http://stackoverflow.com/q/9389874/32453

Comment: http://blog.grepruby.com/2015/04/absolute-url-full-url-in-rails-4.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this plugin:

http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/10/actionmailer-and-host-value/

and it works great!

Answer (score 51):

If you use the `_url` suffix, the generated URL is absolute. Use `_path` to get a relative URL.

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_url %>

<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
```

Comment: That works fine from a regular view, but from a mailer I am not having as much luck...

Comment: In Mailer you need to pass or configure a default host.

Comment: What happens if the host is dynamic though. *.domain.com?

Comment: This is awesome. I can do `route_name_url(param)` with that instead of `route_name_path(param)`. It's that easy.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on your use case, string interpolation might be a good solution:

```
link_to(body, "http://#{site_url}")
```

Answer (score 0):

In routes.rb insert :

```
root :to => 'controller#action'
```

Or replace your current map.root with the correct one.

See documentation about this : [routes.rb usage](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Pretty sure that "map" in routes.rb is for Rails 2 only.