# Create mail in Mailer that include links

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I create a mail which works fine as long as I do not add a link inside the body. 
I am looking to have an email that is send to a recipient once a message is directed to him on the platform.

`<%= link_to "See message", @message %>` does not seem to work. Is there a specific approach for the problem ? All what I saw so far is not very clear.

The error message is :

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Rails::Mailers#preview
```

Message-mailer.rb file :

```
class MessageMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def new_message(message)
    @message = message

    @title = message.title
    @from_first_name = User.find_by_id(message.user_id).first_name
    @from_last_name = User.find_by_id(message.user_id).last_name


    mail to: @message.user.email,
         subject: "New Message: #{@message.title}"

  end
end
```

Comment: Can you put your mailer code?

Answer (score 0):

Mailer is not inside the response stack, you need to specify the host or make it default from env.

Similar Answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389874/how-to-include-full-path-in-rails-3-link-to-statement?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#answer-9389996) and Action Mailer [Link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html)

```
<p>Hi <%= "#{@email}"%>,</p>
<p>
    Message Link: <%=  link_to "See Message", 
                        message_url(id: @message.id, host: "http://localhost:3000")%>    
</p>

# development.rb - for default
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost" }
```

Comment: Hi, i just tried, and I have an error again,
`missing required keys: [:id], possible unmatched constraints: [:locale]`

Comment: share yr message_mailer.rb file

Comment: Hello, I just added the file in the original message

Comment: @Etienne just updated my answer `id: @message.id` try like this, forgot using `url` instead `path`.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, i now have the missing Locale key :

`ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"messages", :id=>83}, missing required keys: [:locale])`

Much more difficult than php :(

Comment: @Etienne if using locale, try adding `locale: :us` or nil.